# Assign jquery variable to a angularjs variable

Tags: jquery, angularjs

How can i assign a jquery element to angularjs?
i tried:

```
var scope = $scope;
scope.project = $( "#project" ).val();
```

But it didn't worked for me. Someone has a solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont find any problem in it.What error have you got ?

Comment: You should never run your jquery code inside your controller.Rather than trying to make this work, try to find out how to avoid this.

Comment: Why do you have to do this at all? Can't you add `ng-model="project"` to the input field?

Comment: those input field i generate dynamically. Each field  has a id. For this example, the field Project has the id project. I need that variable for my request, which i send to my server. So i need that variable. I don't like to use $( "#project" ).val();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind a model via `ng-model` attribute to your `input` and access it whenever you want to use it:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10607/)

Moreover, as @Abhishek Jain pointed out, you should never use *jQuery* code within your controller. You could use a directive for that.

Comment: i also tried $scope.project = $("#project").val(); but didn't work. But how do i get those value without using jquery code?

Comment: please provide some more of your code, especially when you want to get the value. fiddle would be nice.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cty7nta1/1/
I'm just testing, what's possible with jquery and angularjs

Comment: Well, normally you would use `ng-model` at this `input`. When you do your ajax call you can access all those scope values by their model. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is the best way:

> put inside your jquery event..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var controllerElement = document.querySelector('[ng-controller="yourController"]');
    var scope = angular.element(controllerElement).scope();
    scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.yourProperty = 'your value';
    });
});
```